# Objective C: use instance class in other class

Tags: objective-c, class, properties

In my code, in an class I have an ivar

```
FirstClass *first;
```

and I can use `first` within an instance of this class.
But if I want to access `first` from another object instance (or even another class), how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a property. Probably in your header of your second class something like

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) FirstClass *first;
```

and in your implementation

```
@synthesize first;
```

Than when you create an object of your `SecondClass`

```
SecondClass *second = [[SecondClass alloc] init];
```

you can use

```
second.first
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're talking about using FirstClass in another source file than its own, right?

In this case you'd have to import its header by adding this to the top of your second class' ".m"-file:

```
#import "FirstClass.h"
```

If you also need to reference in your second class' header ".h"-file, then you can add a

```
@class FirstClass;
```

before the `@interface` block. This will tell the compiler that it should consider a class of that name to be existant, but to not bother you with warnings unless you forget to import the given first class' ".h" file in the second class' ".m" file.

To allow access from foreign objects to your SecondClass' firstClass iVar you'll need to implement a getter method for firstClass.

This is done with

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, retain) FirstClass *firstClass;
```

in the `@interface` block, and

```
@synthesize firstClass;
```

in the `@implementation` block.

With this set up you can then either call `[secondClassInstance firstClass];` or access it via the dot syntax `secondClassInstance.firstClass;`.
My sample will also synthesize a setter method called `setFirstClass:`. To make the property read-only, change `readwrite` to `readonly` in the `@property` declaration.

Sample:

**FirstClass.h:**

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface FirstClass : NSObject {
@private

}

//method declarations

@end
```

**FirstClass.m:**

```
#import "FirstClass.h"

@implementation FirstClass

//method implementations

@end
```

**SecondClass.h:**

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@class FirstClass;

@interface SecondClass : NSObject {
@private
    FirstClass *firstClass;
}

@property (nonatomic, readwrite, retain) FirstClass *firstClass;

//method declarations

@end
```

**SecondClass.m:**

```
#import "SecondClass.h"

#import "FirstClass.h"

@implementation SecondClass

@synthesize firstClass;

- (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init]) != nil) {
        firstClass = [FirstClass alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [firstClass release];
    [super dealloc];
}

//method implementations

@end
```

Comment: FirstClass *first; is declared in a secondclass and I want to use "first" in Firstclass, ok?

Comment: Added property declaration. Check my answer again.